# Addin a Button on keylock screen ANDROID

Tags: android

For my application., I must add a button to start my
appl. on key lock screen between unlock button.How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ff214f3f87965dbc/7fc3d0b60de8ba8a?lnk=gst&q=lock+screen#7fc3d0b60de8ba8a

Check this thread - i think it's still not supported.